# Using Javascript what's the difference between an expression in variable assignment context, and outside of the context?

Tags: javascript

## SPOILER

I'm trying to [solve problem #8](http://escape.alf.nu/8/) of this Javascript injection game.

In one of the comments by [Erling Ellingsen](https://www.facebook.com/erling), I found this interesting snippet.

> (_=[].concat)()[0]

What's the difference between the above snippet, and this,

> ([].concat)()[0]

What changes when you assign `[].concat` to a variable? Clearly, he's just trying to access the global window object, but how do these two evaluate differently?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this *previously* worked was because it was specified in a previous version of ECMAScript that the this value would be the global object (i.e. `window`). However, from ECMAScript 5 onwards, the this value is now `undefined`, which make `Array.prototype.concat` throws an error.

In ES3, if a native function got called with a `this` value of `undefined` or `null` (such as when you call it using `func()`), it would provide the global object to the function.

In ES5, the behaviour of native functions has been changed so that it gets the actual `undefined` or `null` value, even though your code is not in strict mode.

---

The difference between the two is that one is the value of the function, and therefore is indirectly called, while the other is a reference to the function.

`GetValue()` is an internal function that gets the value of a reference from a variable - this is not called when calling "directly", but when assigning to another variable and using the result of that, it is indeed called ([source](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1)).

An infamous example of the difference between the two is when using `eval()`:

```
var a = 0;
function test()
{   var a = 1, b;
    console.log(eval("a")); // 1
    console.log((b=eval)("a")); // 0
}
test();
```

In your example though, it works like the following:

```
var a = [].concat;
// called as variable, not property
a(); // therefore it's global

// same as the following, as all these expressions call GetValue() interally
(0, [].concat)();
(random = [].concat)();
([].concat || 0)();

// but this doesn't work
[].concat(); // `this` is the new array, not global object
```

Comment: but this === window inside of the function, no? `( function () { return this===window } )()` regardless of what gets ThisBinding, and what gets the window object, wouldn't the effect be the same if both of the variables are the same? Sorry, but still not getting it.